# fgets not blocking for input - C

Tags: c, stdin, scanf, fgets

I'm writing a program for school; it's my first time working with C.

I'm using fgets to read input, but sometimes fgets doesn't block (throwing the program into an infinite loop). To answer everyone's first question, no, I'm not using scanf before hand leaving the extra `\n` which would cause this issue. I am using sscanf at one point, but that's in association with fgets so I assume that's not the issue.

There is some code that was given to us dealing with sockets. I've looked through it and can't find the source of the issue. The code isn't included due to length, but I can include it if that helps.

Long story short, is there any reason fgets wouldn't block for input apart from the scanf issue? Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I should have made this more clear earlier, but in this case I'm using fgets solely for stdin.

Comment: Are you checking whether `fgets` returned an error?

Comment: Read the manual for `fgets`. Reread the first sentence of this comment. Make sure you process the return value of `fgets` once you understand it.

Comment: Yes, it won't block if it encounters an error.  Check the error code set in errno.

Comment: ah! thanks. `fgets` is returning `null`, and `errno` is set to 9. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As with most standard functions in C, you'll need to do a little digging around to figure out what's happening. The best place to start is with the function documentation.

[fgets() documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

From this documentation, we can see that fgets takes three parameters and returns a char*. Asuming the parameters are correct, the function will read from the stream until it reaches a new-line character or the end of file marker. In the case of success, the return code will be a pointer to the str parameter.

The case your probably more interested in, though, is the failure case. On failure, the function returns NULL. To determine how exactly the failure takes place, you need to check the file error indicator and see if it has printed a message. This can be done as follows:

```
if ( fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile) == NULL )
{
    // We handle error here
    if (ferror (pFile))
    {
        printf ("We encountered an error!\n");
        perror ("Error message");
    }
}
```

From here, you should be able to determine what is happening. The likely cause is a invalid parameter or a parameter that is not in the format/condition expected.

Comment: thanks for the response! I looked into it further, and fgets is returning null, and errno is populated with 9. still don't know why that would be though...

Comment: A quick search shows that a code of 9 is usually associated with _Bad File Descriptor_. This likely means that the third argument of `fgets()` is incorrect. Perhaps the stream is not initialized or configured yet? It sounds like you're either passing the wrong parameter or the parameter you're passing is correct, but not yet in a state where `fgets()` can use it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found as well. Unfortunately, it's only being used with stdin

Comment: Are you including `<stdio.h>`?

Comment: Yeah. It breaks the second or third time it's being used. I'm thinking something must be messing with stdin and making it unavailable, but I just don't have enough experience with C to know what that could be.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question but I thought I'd share what I found when I had this issue. Without your code I can't tell if this is the same issue you had but what I found in my own code was that I was using `close()` on file descriptors that were set to 0. Being curious I looked up what file descriptor 0 was in the system and low and behold stdin is FD 0 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). I'm sure there are many ways of resolving this but in my case I used a simple if statement arround my close:

```
if(fd > 2)
{
close(fd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same issue after retro-fitting some code to allow input from stdin, instead of only reading from a file name argument. The existing code was always calling `close(file)`, even if `file` was set to `stdin`.

Now I only call close if file wasn't replaced with stdin, and the issue is resolved, because stdin is no longer prematurely closed.

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same issue**. I was using both fget and scanf in the same program. When i changed everything to fget, the issue disappeared.

Changed all the scanf:

```
printf("[?]Enter a name for saving the file: ");
scanf("%99s", fileName);
```

To fget:

```
printf("[?]Enter a name for saving the file: ");
fgets(fileName, sizeof(fileName), stdin);
fileName[strcspn(fileName, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Comment: Got the hypothesis from a LLM:
"You may be mixing fgets with scanf or other functions that may leave a newline character (\n) in the input stream. This causes fgets to return immediately with that single newline"